extension of a geodesic is no more minimal geodesic
Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:\mathbb{R}\to M$ be two different geodesics such that $\gamma_1(a)=\gamma_2(a)$ and $\gamma_1(b)=\gamma_2(b)$ and $\exists c\in (a,b)$, s.t. $\gamma_1(c)\ne\gamma_2(c)$. I want to show that for any small extension $\gamma_1|_{[a,b+\epsilon]}:[a,b+\epsilon]\to \mathbb{R}$, it is not a geodesic with minimal length. My rough idea is that the curve $\gamma_2|_{[a,b]}\cup\gamma_1|{[b,b+\epsilon]}$ has the same length with $\gamma_1|_{[a,b+\epsilon]}$, but it's not smooth, then it's not geodesic, also can't have minimal length.
But I have a question to determine if this idea works: How can I say $\gamma_2|_{[a,b]}\cup\gamma_1|_{[b,b+\epsilon]}$ is not smooth? Wouldn't there be a situation here involving a partition of unity, something like $e^{-x^2}$ such that different curve can be glued smoothly?

Have you tried the simplest possible example where this occurs?

No, I think such example doesn't exist. However, I can't rule out this situation. For example, consider a "certain" metric on $S^2$ where two different meridians connecting antipodal points are "pinched together" at the intersection point.

Of course examples exist. Take the usual round metric on the sphere and take two different geodesics joining a pair of antipodal points.

Yes, we are the same. I mean, the kind of situation described in my question seems impossible to occur.

Do you know that geodesics are uniquely determined by their initial velocities? But in your question you should assume that both geodesics have unit speed (or the same constant positive speed).

Yes I know. Thank you for the hint, I know it now, that situation cannot occur simply because they must have different final velocity vector. The both geodesics have of course the same positive speed because the interval length and curve length are the same.
